# Cast from 'AFError?' to unrelated type 'URLError' always fails warning

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm getting this warning `Cast from 'AFError?' to unrelated type 'URLError' always fails` when I try to cast the error in the following function

```
func requestBlock() {
    struct ValidationConsumer: ResponseDelegate {
        weak var syncRequest: Transfer_PurchaseValidation?
        var productIdentifier: String

        func didSucceed(_ _: JSON, _ _: AFDataResponse<Any>?) {
            DDLogInfo("Purchase payload for productId = \(productIdentifier) was sent")
            syncRequest?.didSucceed()
        }

        func didFail(_ json: JSON, _ code: Int?, _ dataResponse: AFDataResponse<Any>?) {
            syncRequest?.didFail(with: .PurchaseValidationError(code,
                    dataResponse?.error as? URLError))
        }
    }

    guard data.shouldBeTransferred else {
        return
    }

    guard isUnderTest == nil else {
        executeTestsequence()
        return
    }

    guard let receiptDataString = data.receiptDataString,
          let productIdentifier = data.productIdentifier else {
        didFail(with: .InvalidData); return
    }

    let validationConsumer = ValidationConsumer(syncRequest: self,
            productIdentifier: productIdentifier)
    self.validatePurchase(receiptDataString, productIdentifier,
            validationDelegate: validationConsumer)
}
```

at this part `syncRequest?.didFail(with: .PurchaseValidationError(code, dataResponse?.error as? URLError))`

I tried to use `NSError` or `Error` classes but no success.

Can anyone let me know how I can get rid of this warning?

Thanks in advance

Comment: hi Muhammad, For what reason do you want to convert? for example get http response code like 200 or else?

Comment: This is for the error part. So, it's only for failure cases.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The solution was to add another cast.
So, instead of

```
syncRequest?.didFail(with: .PurchaseValidationError(code,

                    dataResponse?.error as? URLError))
```

I did the case as following

```
syncRequest?.didFail(with: .PurchaseValidationError(code, 
                    dataResponse?.error as NSError? as? URLError))
```

Comment: This isn't correct either. The cast works but it won't preserve the right error information.

Answer (score 5):

Alamofire returns `AFError` instances by default which are not convertible to `URLError`. You can examine the `AFError` documentation or source code for the full details, but underlying errors like network failures are exposed through the `underlyingError` property. So in the case of a network failure, `response?.error?.underlyingError as? URLError` should give you the correct value, but only *if* the underlying error is actually a `URLError`.

Ultimately I suggest you handle the `AFError` directly, as it's the only full representation of all of the errors Alamofire can return. Either that, or your own error type which does the handling for you. Casting is not the correct way to capture these errors, as any cast will lose some error information.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem similar to yours.
I made a model as follows:

```
struct MyErorr: Error {
    
    public var errorCode: Int
    public var erorrMessage: String
}
```

and create object from myError this error part like this:

```
// error instance from AFError

if error.responseCode == 401 {
    let myError: MyErorr = .init(errorCode: 401, erorrMessage: "Unauthorized")
    callback(myError)
    
} else { ... }
```

I hope it is useful for you